# Getting the crontab text template from within a bash script

Tags: crontab

`crontab -e` initially picks up a text template, apparently from this file https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-cron/pkg-cron.git/tree/crontab.c. I'd like to programatically fetch that block of text, so I can then append lines with cron jobs at the end of the template, so it would look like a manually edited cron file.

`crontab -e > somefile` doesn't work, because it gets stuck at an interactive shell.

`crontab -l > somefile` also doesn't work, because there is no crontab file when an user account is created.

I could try and `sed` the text template, but where would it be located in a running system? And also, would it be present in say an image (Ubuntu) deployed by a hosting provider, or would I need to add the sources repo to apt list first?

Maybe an easier way would be to `export VISUAL=nano; crontab -e` and then send Ctrl+o, Enter, Ctrl+X to create a new crontab file without user interaction? But how do I send key strokes to an interactive shell inside a bash script?

Comment: Plz explain more about your issue. It's unclear what you want to do when the user is just created and has no working cron file. you may find some templates in /etc.

Comment: I found it, kind of manually, in https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-cron/pkg-cron.git/tree/crontab.c
So how can I programatically get this block of text into a Bash script?
It's the block of text starting at line 592.

Comment: remove \n and " and you can put it in a bash script

Comment: you need to add more to your problem. you need to say which parameters of a crontab line do you want fixed and which you want to customize, e.g. dates, hours or the program to run

Comment: In the case of Ubuntu, the source files are usually not present, unless the source repo is selected? Say in a server image from a hosting provider.

Comment: Then I'd have to sed the file to extract that block of text? I just want to use the original text as template, when programatically creating a crontab file for a new user, simple as that. Otherwise, it will just be an empty file with the new jobs. It's a cosmetic, ocd-ish thing. I'm sorry if I'm wasting your time.

Comment: not at all, but your post is vague and way different from your comments. please update the post with that link and details and all.

Answer (score 0):

Since the template is embedded in the `crontab` program itself, there is no need for it to exist in any other file.

To extract it on a system where you don't have a crontab, try temporarily setting your editor to `touch`.

```
VISUAL=touch crontab -e
crontab -l >saved
```

You might also be able to extract it with `strings`, or just embed it as a here document in your own script.

Comment: user@vps:~$ VISUAL=touch crontab -e  
no crontab for user - using an empty one  
No modification made

Comment: Could you expand on your 2 other suggestions?

Comment: Copy/paste it from the source file you found on the web. You might be able to do something similar by running `strings` on the local `crontab` binary but the ouput tends to be fairly noisy.

Comment: ... Or replace `touch` with a simpie `sed` script which adds a comment. The syntax varies between dialects but try `VISUAL='sed -i \$a\\#' crontab -e`